# How can I redefine a property value in .sh file when starting a Java application

Tags: java, bash

I have a script file app.sh:
`java -DenabledFeature=true -jar filename [args]`

When I launch the script:
`./app.sh -DenabledFeature=false`

Where in code
`Boolean isFeatureEnabled = System.getProperty("enabledFeature", "true").equals("true")`

the value is always true;

How can I change the value of the property to false?

Comment: You have to evaluate the command line parameter in your shell script and pass the value to the java call. Currently the value is hardcoded in your script.See e.g. https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php

Comment: The special syntax with -Dname=value is Java specific. It has no effect for the shell.

Comment: I need to change the value using the shell

Comment: Yes, I know. And what exactly is your problem now? You even got an answer which you can use as a starting point. You should learn a little bit of shell script programming. This is still programming only on a different level.

Comment: thank you i have no problem now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you always run your application by `./app.sh -DenabledFeature=false`, you can directly pass the command line arguments as java arguments by this:

```
java $1 -jar filename [args]
```

here `$1` will capture the `sh` first argument.

**Update** as you can pass several values as arguments, you can check if you have pass false value for enable feature like:

---

**app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

enabledFeature=true
if [[ "$*" =~ '-DenabledFeature=false']] ;
then
      enabledFeature=false
      #echo $enabledFeature
fi

java -DenabledFeature=$enabledFeature -jar filename [args]
```

---

Comment: I want that the default value is "true":
`./app.sh` and `./app.sh -DenabledFeature=true` should gave the same thing, i mean feature should be enabled by default; in case i need to disable the feature i use `./app.sh -DenabledFeature=false`

Comment: In your described case, my proposed answer should work. because the `$1` supplied argument is empty and System.getProperty("enabledFeature", **"true"**) will return true as `enabledFeature` not exists and default value returning from there is `true`.

Comment: it works if I am not using other arguments, but the problem if I use an argument `-en` 
it will be considered as an option and it will not be recognized
(I have 4 arguments that I can use)

Comment: how to make difference between options and arguments

Comment: You should probably quote `$1`. Also it may make sense to use `$@` to not be limited to one argument. Finally, you could leave the default argument in place (`-DenabledFeature=true` as the OP had) and let additional arguments override. (Maybe double check that repeated definitions override each other.)